# Where should I put leafelt-<script> tags in HTML markup and can I use async or defer?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a question about optimally integrating leaflet into the HTML document.

I have read this: [Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-should-i-put-script-tags-in-html-markup/24070373#24070373)

If I interpret this information correctly, then if possible, you should include JavaScript with the attribute async or defer. And if possible you should put the Js-files into the -element.

The `Leaflet.js` must be fully loaded for a map to be displayed. Therefore, I can not use the attribute "async". But I can use the attribute "defer". The best place for integrating the leaflet.js is the -element.

After that I have to integrate my individual JavaScript code with the defer-attribute, so that it executes after leaflet.js.I have to put this js-file after the div that holds my map.

**Is this correct or could there be a problem with using defer and is there a better place to integrate the js-files?**

**I ask this question, because I do not see this attributes async or defer in the examples on the website http://leafletjs.com/examples/.**

Thank you for an answer.

---

This is my example code that runs without error:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Eine OSM Karte mit Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
<body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js" defer></script>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  <script src="mymap_99.js" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where the file `mymap_99.j`s is a short test map:

```
var map = L.map('map',
{
  center: [50.27264, 7.26469],
  zoom: 10
});
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

---

Crossposting: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leaflet-js/fRC9ElCtFaY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right in that your second script depends on the first being loaded but that does not mean you can’t use `async`.

if you wait for the load event to fire, you can be sure the leaflet library has loaded before trying to use it:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Eine OSM Karte mit Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.1.0/dist/leaflet.js" async></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  <script>
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var map = L.map('map',
      {
        center: [50.27264, 7.26469],
        zoom: 10
      }
    );
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
  }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think if at all possible it’s better to use `async` than `defer` (because async scripts give the browser more flexibility for when to load and when to execute). In this case you could use `async` for both scripts (provided you wait for the load event before drawing the map).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

Do you know why `leaflet` is rarely used with the attribute `async`?

Comment: @astridx I would assume the documentation tries to be as concise as possible and concentrate on showing how leaflet itself can be used and assumes the user is familiar with the various methods that can be used to load JavaScript code…

Comment: just wondering if this is considered best practise these days? tx